# Django - Tag inside a Template tag

Tags: python, django

So I'm using the `django-jcrop` plugin to crop an image. Inside my HTML file I have this line:

```
<img src="{% cropped_thumbnail order 'cropping' max_size='{{ ratio }}' %}">
```

When this is passed, I get the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: max_size must match INTxINT
```

`{{ ratio }}` is passed correctly outside of the tag, and gives the correct intended value, 400x400. When I remove the single quotes from the `max_size='{{ ratio }}'` I then get the following error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'
```

So I am pretty sure ratio is not parsing correctly within the tag. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside a template tag you don't need to use the "{{}}", you can try the next code:

```
<img src="{% cropped_thumbnail order 'cropping' max_size=ratio %}">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've had my head wrapped around this for hours